# Developing Kibana plugin using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kibana

I would like to create a Kibana plugin using ReactJS as the preferred javascript framework. It seems like is possible, but the documentation and examples are definitely sparse. I have set up the local environment as far as running Kibana, `kbn bootstrap` etc and modified the `app.js` as one would when working with a react application.

In the `index.js` of the plugin I have

```
  app: {
    title: 'Reactisearch',
    description: 'Sample Kibana plugin using ReactJS and Elasticsearch',
    main: 'plugins/reactisearch/app'
  },
```

in the `uiExports`. My only trouble is that traditionally in a React application the `index.html` would be elsewhere with a target element in the DOM for the app to render to. I can't seem to get this portion working. I do have

`ReactDOM.render(<Base />,document.getElementById('root'));`

within the `app.js` as you normally would but it is apparent there is a disconnect from there on. I understand if you were using Kibana's(Angular) routing you could do something like

```
uiRoutes.enable();
uiRoutes
  .when('/', {
    template,
    ...
  });
```

where the template is referring to the angular template but since I am not trying to use angular, then what?

Bottom line is would like to develop most (if not all) of the plugin in React, but if there must be a little angular I suppose that is okay. This is only the second day even looking at Kibana so sorry if some of this stuff is obvious.

If it matters I am targeting the latest of everything.

Comment: is the line `ReacDOM.render(..)` executing? is it throwing an error?

Comment: Correct. `Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element`. It is obvious why because I'm not saying that `index.html` is the entry point into the application anywhere. Webpack would normally take care of that in a simple React app, but I don't know how to declare that within a Kibana plugin.

Comment: so that doesn't actually matter.. you just need *any* dom element to attach to. i'm going to try and whip up a quick example since I have a kibana plugin to write on my todolist. standby

Comment: I have created example for kibana react plugin, you can see here : https://github.com/satishwaghela/kibana-react-visualisation-example